# libev pass argument to callback

Tags: c, io, libev

When we call `ev_io_init` we give it a function address that has `(struct ev_loop*, struct ev_io, int)` parameters but how we can make parameters like `(struct ev_loop*, struct ev_io, int, void *ptr)` and make `ev_io_init` call it with constant ptr value?

I know how to carry extra data from `struct ev_io*` but saving same data for every different event is not good way i guess

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [the documentation](http://pod.tst.eu/http://cvs.schmorp.de/libev/ev.pod#ASSOCIATING_CUSTOM_DATA_WITH_A_WATCH):

> ## ASSOCIATING CUSTOM DATA WITH A WATCHER
>
> Each watcher has, by default, a `void *data` member that you can read
>   or modify at any time: libev will completely ignore it. This can be
>   used to associate arbitrary data with your watcher. If you need more
>   data and don't want to allocate memory separately and store a pointer
>   to it in that data member, you can also "subclass" the watcher type
>   and provide your own data:
>
> ```
> struct my_io
> {
>   ev_io io;
>   int otherfd;
>   void *somedata;
>   struct whatever *mostinteresting;
> };
>
> ...
> struct my_io w;
> ev_io_init (&w.io, my_cb, fd, EV_READ);
> ```
>
> And since your callback will be called with a pointer to the watcher,
>   you can cast it back to your own type:
>
> ```
> static void my_cb (struct ev_loop *loop, ev_io *w_, int revents)   
> {
>   struct my_io *w = (struct my_io *)w_;
>   ...
> }
> ```
>
> More interesting and less C-conformant ways of casting your callback
>   function type instead have been omitted.

Since you just want to pass one pointer, the easiest way is definitely just sticking it in the `data` field.